# I am unable to import psycopg2 from Jupyter notebook or Jupyter Lab on Mac. I have a clean install of Catalina

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, psycopg2, jupyter-lab

A similar report was posted, but the suggested solutions do not work.

```
---- from Jupyter ----

Import psycopg2
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-7d2da0a5d979> in <module>
----> 1 import psycopg2

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

If I run `python3` from Mac terminal and then `import psycopg2` that works.
If I run `python3` from Jupyterlab terminal this does not work. I get the following error after running `import pyscopg2`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libssl.1.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

`echo $PATH` from Mac terminal is

```
/Users/greg/opt/miniconda3/bin:/Users/greg/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

`echo $PATH` from Jupyterlab terminal is

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/greg/opt/miniconda3/bin:/Users/greg/opt/anaconda3/condabin
```

These look the same, just in a different order.

I have tried `pip install psycopg2` both with and without the binary option.Either way, it says already satisfied.
I have tried

```
conda install -c anaconda psycopg2
```

Also tried installing postgresql both from the postgresql.org, and `brew install psycopg2`. Both worked, but no luck with Jupyterlab.

Answer (score 3):

try installing the package using: pip install psycopg2-binary. This should work.
For more information, visit: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html